# Using macOS Terminal, how to batch rename dotfiles so that they become regular files?

Tags: terminal, mojave, macos, invisible-files

When working with visible files, the usual process is to select all the files that need renaming, right click, and select 'rename (x number of) files'.

When working with invisible files (specifically dotfiles), the 'rename (x number of) files' option is not offered.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I'm going to assume all files are the same type, and are .otf files.

```
for file in .*.otf
do
echo mv "$file" "${file/./}"
done
```

This will perform a dry-run of the renaming process.

If the results appear correct, run it again without 'echo'.

Comment: Even if it is not a problem in this case, it might be safer to use `${file/#./}` to make sure only a leading dot is removed. Or even `${file#.}` which cuts off the leading dot as well.